# How to start notification on different time periods

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

I have activity that pop notifications.For this I get all five time values from `WebService`.They are different time (no pattern).So I used an `AlarmManager` to set the notifications as follows.

```
Intent[] intentArr = new Intent[5];
PendingIntent[] pendingIntent = new PendingIntent[5];
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
 intentArr[x] = new Intent(con, NotificationIntentService.class);
 intentArr[x].putExtra("gamePlayerId", bamDaoList.get(x).getGamePlayerId());
intentArr[x].putExtra("bamReactionId",bamDaoList.get(x).getBamReactionId());
pendingIntent[x] = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(con, x, intentArr[x],PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time[x], pendingIntent[x]);
}
```

This pops notifications.But not at exact time.Is there any way of doing this or what is the wrong with my code?

`NotificationIntentService.class` is for defining the notification.

Comment: Couple of questions: 1. how are you calculating your time value?  2. what is your `targetSdkVersion` set to in your manifest?

Comment: 1. I get time in milliseconds from the webService.And I need to set Notification for that time with alarmManager. 2. targetSdkVersion is 22

Answer (score 1):

In my app i am doing the same thing . I use alarm manger for reminders .

In order to do it i use the following code:

```
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("custom://" + objectId)); // objectId is the identifier (in my app its a string) 
    intent.setAction(objectId);
    intent.putExtra(Constants.FIELD_OBJECT_ID, objectId);

    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);  // Zeros seconds

    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), alarmIntent);
```

Let me explain ,

1. I set alarm manager instance
2. I create a new intent with a broadcast receiver (don't forget to register the broadcast receiver in manifest.xml before)
3. i use action in order to know on which id i set this alarm so when the alarm will fire i will be able to extract this objectId and do something with it ..
4. Then i create a calendar instance set a Date object into it and set seconds to 0 just to make sure it will be fired exactly on time
5. Last i set alarm manager

In your code you don't need to create array of pending intents you can just wrap this code in a method that will receive the objectId, Date and Context and call it every time you need it with the relevant id then in the Broadcast Receiver you will extract the objectId and do something with it.

---

### How to test it

in order to test i recommend to get the time now with +10 or 15 seconds 
to get the time with 15 seconds from now please use the following method

```
public static Calendar calWithSecondsFromNow(int seconds) {
    Date now = new Date();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(now);
    cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, seconds);
    return cal;
}
```

this method will return you the date now with + the seconds that you will send to the parameter .
take the result of it and put it in the set method .

Also please make sure that you **Registered the Broadcast Receiver in the manifest.xml file**

Let me know if it worked.

---

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the response but what is  cal.setTime(date);
 cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0); And I need to set five notifications by using alarmManager.How can I do it

Comment: Using calendar object you have full control on the date so your method should get some Date object (java.util.Date) which is the time when the alarm will be fired and then you use calendar in order to set the seconds to zero

Comment: but I get milliseconds from the web service.How can I convert it as Date object ?If I use above code snippet with a loop then all five alarms will be set.Am I right??

Comment: if you have a milliseconds then you don't need to date object you can set the miili seconds into the Calendar object .. in this case you can ignore the date

Comment: I tried It but the notifications did not poped out at the correct time?

Comment: Maybe you can test it by sending the current date (maybe with +10 seconds), set the alarm and wait until it will fired in order to do that please have a look at the edited answer

Answer (score 1):

If your `targetSdkVersion` >= 19, then you'll need to use:

```
alarmManager.setExact(...);
```

From api level 19 an on, `AlarmManager.set(...)` does not guarentee exact delivery time.  See the documentation for `AlarmManager`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

> Note: Beginning in API 19, the trigger time passed to this method is treated as inexact: the alarm will not be delivered before this time, but may be deferred and delivered some time later. The OS will use this policy in order to "batch" alarms together across the entire system, minimizing the number of times the device needs to "wake up" and minimizing battery use. In general, alarms scheduled in the near future will not be deferred as long as alarms scheduled far in the future.
>
> With the new batching policy, delivery ordering guarantees are not as strong as they were previously. If the application sets multiple alarms, it is possible that these alarms' actual delivery ordering may not match the order of their requested delivery times. If your application has strong ordering requirements there are other APIs that you can use to get the necessary behavior; see setWindow(int, long, long, PendingIntent) and setExact(int, long, PendingIntent).
>
> Applications whose targetSdkVersion is before API 19 will continue to get the previous alarm behavior: all of their scheduled alarms will be treated as exact.